# Numbers in the wheel

Tags: logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers

Arrange the numbers 3 to 27 onto the wheel using these rules:

- The modulus of two adjacent numbers must equal with the number between them.
- Modulus here means the remainder when the bigger number is divided by the smaller number.
- 5 numbers are given to get you started.

[image]

Comment: I saw the puzzle and I knew it would be you.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I have a unique character of my puzzles. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> [image]
>
>  Didn't get much of a logical insight, sadly. The best i could do from the initial configuration is to narrow possibilities down to 2-4 possibilities for some of the 4-number 'segment's. Ended up just bruteforcing the problem to get into this solution.